# Widget Size for OpenPeak Open Tablet 7

Tags: android

The OpenTablet 7 Homescreen grid is a 5x5 on a 1024x600 resolution.  If I am correct, would I design a homescreen widget to be 409.6x240 in landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question for info on Widget sizes:

- [Android Widget Bitmap Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636767/android-widget-bitmap-sizes)

**EDIT**
I see no reason why this wouldn't also apply to a 5x5 layout.  The exact size depends on the number of cells you want your Widget to use.  The formula is:

```
(number of cells * 74) - 2
```

So 5 x 2 would be: 368dp x 146dp.  Note these are dp not px values.  You can then calculate your pixel values, using:

```
pixels = dps * (density / 160)
```

so your hdpi (240) resource would be: 552px x 219px

Comment: Does this still pertain to a grid of 5x5?

Comment: @taraloca I've added some more details, please check the maths though!

Comment: Thanks Dave!! Much appreciated!  I will post back to let anyone know how it works out.

Comment: Yes, I found that this formula works with a 4x4 and 5x5 grid alike.